# Javascript newbie issue, converting a number to any word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So frustrated with my issue, totally over my head trying to add a small feature to my site. I don't really know what I'm doing and I'm trying to use the HTML input range, with a text box that labels the value of the slider.

So I have this so far...

```
<input id="Slider" type="range" min="0" max="2" value="2" />
<p class="note">Current value: <span id="currentValue">0</span></p>
<script>
  $(function(){

  var currentValue = $('#currentValue');

  $('#Slider').change(function(){
      currentValue.html(this.value);
  });

  $('#Slider').change();

  });
</script>
```

It works fine, sometimes it doesn't always update the number, but outputs the numbers 0, 1, and 2.

I need to know how to convert 0 to a word, like... apple, 1 to orange, and 2 to banana, or whatever I wish the words to be.

Thank you for any help you can provide. Also, if there is a better / more efficient way to accomplish this that would be nice as well, thank you.

Comment: Try creating an array: `var values = ["apple", "orange", "banana"];` and then use `currentValue.html(values[this.value]);`. 0 will refer to "apple", 1 to "orange", etc.

Comment: thank you! that worked and was so simple too. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You would use an array to and `.html()` to change the text (how @Ian commented).
An improved version of the slider with the word changing:

HTML

```
<p id="word">Number 0 has been chosen</p>

<input type="range" id="Slider" type="range" min="0" max="2" value="0">
```

JS/JQuery

```
var n = ["Number 0 has been chosen", "Number 1 has been chosen", "Number 2 has been chosen"];

$('#Slider').on('change', function(){
    $('#word').html(n[this.value]);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3BCtd/)